# Database foreign key to spring translation

Tags: sql, database, spring, hibernate, rest

I have a database model consisting of 3 tables: `dog`, `cat` and a `shelter`.

`dog` has 3 attributes and those are: `id` (primary key), `name`, `age`
`cat` has 3 attributes and those are: `id` (primary key), `name`, `sex`

`shelter` has 4 attributes and those are:
`id` (primary key),
`dog_id` (foreign key to `dog`'s `id`,
`cat's id` (foreign key to `cat`'s `id`,
`space` (indicates number of free space)

Does foreign key means it's a 1to1 relationship? How to model the entities in Spring framework? If I use PostgreSQL ir MySQL, do I need to implement database in Spring or can it be done other way?

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key is just an attribute which is used to establish relationship between two entities. The relationship could be anything (oneToOne/OneToMany/ManytoMany).

In your case, it most likely oneToOne relationship assuming a shelter is shared between cat and dog.

This has nothing to do with Spring. Spring is a framework where you can wire classes and write businesslogic - in a nutshell.